# HTML special character (glyph) looking not the same in different browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser

I am using an html crown in my website, character code is `&#9819;`, but this looks different in the browsers.

```
Firefox 6.0 -> different
Chrome 13.0 -> different
IE 9.0, Safari 5.1, Opera 11.50 -> same
```

I have tried to explicit add a font-family to the span, but this does not help.

Anyone have an idea how I can get this the same in the browsers.

Check this post in differnt browsers and see how the char (glyph) changes. **♛**

Comment: It looks the same to me in Opera and Chrome, but just prints a square in IE9 (all of them on Windows).

Comment: Which versions of opera and chrome are you running, Ill edit in my versions.

Comment: Opera 11.10, Chrome 11.0.696.68.

Comment: "see how the char changes" BTW: it's the same character everywhere—it's just [another glyph](http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/forms_of_unicode/#h7).

Comment: @ feeela thank you for pointing out the difference between a glyph and a char. Do you also know how to keep the same in different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After knowing that the correct name is a glyph I have searched for a solution, but it cannot be done. There are only 3 things you can do.

1) Use the @font-face in css with a special font that has the character. The character will display the same in all browsers.

2) Choose your audience: Just restrict access to the website for certain browsers, tell them to change browser.

3) Just leave it like it is, some glyphs change only slightly.

Answer (score -1):

Since your preferred glyph is a graphic, I would suggest an alternative you didn't mention. It is the one recommended back when Wingding fonts were disallowed from the HTML standard. If you want to use an image, use an actual image. SVG would be idea if all your supported browsers can handle it. Otherwise, use a sufficiently large PNG to cover the largest font you plan to use. (I suggest allowing for at least 150% increase in your largest font for those who magnify their screen due to vision difficulties.)